# php 5.4 not working after upgrade from 5.3 to 5.4 on centos 6.5

Tags: php5, centos6.5

Before the update php 5.3.3 worked fine, now the apache offers to download php sites instead of processing them.

What I did:
I used the REMI repo to get php 5.4 for centos 6.5.
I think that all steps have been processed normally.
In /etc/httpd/modules I can find the new files:

```
libphp5-zts.so
libphp5.so
```

I restarted the apache.

Here are some outputs I used to verify that the components work:

```
php -v 
PHP 5.4.28 (cli) (built: May  2 2014 19:09:57)  
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group 
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES 
... 
php5_module (shared)
```

Any ideas what I missed?
Is this a problem of the SELinux?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you still have this line in `apache` config

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

After restart, please test again in **different** browser to bypass caching mechanism on particular browser.

Comment: Did not work this way, but pointed to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.
In my case httpd.conf includes php.conf.
In php.conf I changed in

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

to

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>
```

For some reason they used another naming convention.